# Standard poodle appetite loss

Tags: poodle

I'm having a strange case with my 4 year old male standard poodle and trying to find someone who might have had a similar experience with their pet dog.

About a month ago, I had to move him away from his usual sleeping quarters due to a new baby in the house. Incidentally, during that whole week, there were a lot of fireworks in the area that increased his stress. During that time, he was still having is usual play activities and eating normally at the beginning.

After about two weeks, I noticed he started not finishing his usual meal and drinking much more water and urinating more. He also had a few accidents in the house. I took him to the vet but his blood test and urine test came back normal. The vet also confirmed nothing is wrong with his teeth. His polydipsia/polyuria (drinking a lot/urinating a lot) eventually subsided after 2 weeks.

Nevertheless, his appetite kept decreasing very rapidly especially for meaty stuff. He now doesn't seem to be interested at all in dry food, wet food and minced food. The only things he seems to still like now strangely is some boiled vegetables.

The vet referred for further tests in order to find any physical cause but also said a mental cause is possible. He prescribed Mirtazapine meanwhile to try to stimulate his appetite and it does seem to work though not hugely.

He still eagerly plays ball and still likes to go out but his energy is lower as he has lost some weight.

I'm wondering if anybody had or have heard of anything similar?

EDIT: Turns out he has Addison's Disease. A more thorough and detail blood test showed all the indicators of Addison's. He's been given treatment and is eating again now.

Comment: You mention the baby. How did the new family member influenced the routines for your dog? Did he "loose" privilegs, things he was allowed before, but not now? If you are already aware that it could be mental, then have a close look, if the baby i.e. make you less patient with the dog, or similar. (You can imagine it a similar challange for the dog, as it is for the whole family, to have a baby around :) )

Comment: His routine did get changed as the family would go to sleep at a different time than before. The main privilege he lost I would say was his usual sleeping quarters as his sleeping spot got moved. But the main thing I am not understanding if it were a mental thing could it even lead to total appetite loss in a dog, is that possible or unheard of?

Comment: I am not a dog person. But I can imagine, that changes in the pack's structure could lead to uncertainty in a dog and so the dog could focus on solving this first and forgetting to eat. Pack is more important than food I assume. I know of male dogs who do not eat if there is a female in heat nearby. Mating is more important than food. People say, a dog is cognitive similar to a toddler. And I guess a toddler would react to a new baby also in a visible way.